# Redirect back to previous page doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, redirect

I have url which looks like **example.com/admin/category.php?parent=368**

When I click to see second page it becomes like **example.com/admin/category.php?pageno=2&parent=257**

When I delete product from category I want to redirect me back to same page and I've using

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

This works when I'm on first page but if I'm on second or another page **?pageno=2&parent=257** it redirects me to **&parent=...** it's loosing **pageno=...**

I've tried a lot of solutions here on so but all redirect me back to parent.

I've tried also like this:

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```

but this doesn't refresh the page and I need to refresh it in order to see the result.

Actually ideally should refresh the page and stay on same page..

```
function deleteproduct(prodid) {
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product')) {
        window.location = "del_product.php?act=del&masterCategory=<?=$parent?>&subCategory=<?=$child?>&productID="+prodid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, It's just delete button which delete product. I've updated the button to question.

Comment: If you are deleting the items then why don't you just reload the page after delete? That should resolve the issue.

Comment: @Garg yea aniket is right ..you can try to reload the page after you delete ..you can have a look whether its working or not

Comment: How to reload it instead of `window.location` something like window refresh?

Comment: Inside in above function deleteproduct? I've made it like `window.reload() = "del_product.php?....;` and got `Uncaught TypeError: window.reload is not a function`

Comment: Try `location.reload()` instead of `window.reload`. Your function should be `function deleteproduct() {
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product'))  {
        location.reload();
    }
}`

Comment: But I must pass products id .. cat id .. etc with the function

Comment: if I leave only `location.reload();` inside function .. how will know the product id .. etc.. It's just refreshing the page and didn't delete the product.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128993/discussion-between-aniket-sahrawat-and-garg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `HTTP_REFERRER` you can use `location.reload()` after deleting a item to refresh the changed contents. Below is the example:

```
function deleteproduct(prod) { 
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this product')) { 

        $.get( "del_product.php", { act: "del", 
                                    masterCategory: "<?php echo $parent; ?>", 
                                    subCategory: "<?php echo $child; ?>",
                                    pro‌​ductID: prodid } )
            .done(function( data ) {
                alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
                location.reload();
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Just a note: The correct way which is working for me is `jQuery.get(...` instead of `$.get(...`

Comment: That will be in some cases and not all. By default you should use `$` and if there is a conflict between multiple languages then you can use `jQuery` with `noConflict`